# use a kotlin multiplatform lib in another kotlin multiplatfor lib

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have create a multiplatform kotlin librarie (L1)using intellij in gradle, who build in JS and JVM.

I want to reuse this lib in another multiplatform kotlin lib L2
How can I do it?

I have issue with importing the "common" part of L1 in the common target of L2, (the eror are a lot of `Unresolved reference`), basicaly the common target of L2 cannot find the implementation contained in L1.

I have only this issue with the common target, the js and jvm work fine.

the gradle of L1, the lib to be reused

```
kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnit()
        }
    }
    js(LEGACY) {
        browser {
            testTask {
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                    webpackConfig.cssSupport.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the gradle of L2,the lib who reuse L1:

```
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
         
            implementation("groupId:L1:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
        }
    }
    val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {

            implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
            implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
        }
    }
    val jvmMain by getting {
        dependencies {

           
            implementation("groupId:L1-jvm:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
        }
    }
    val jvmTest by getting {
        dependencies {

            implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
        }
    }
    val jsMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("groupId:L1-js:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
        }
    }
    val jsTest by getting {
        dependencies {

            implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which library is it? With [Kotlin 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#specifying-dependencies-only-once) most libraries don't require you to specify each variant of the library. So you will need to add it as a dependency into common and each platform target will use it.

Comment: I use kotlin 1.4, but I still have the error, even by putting the dep only in common.

Comment: What are dependencies L1 and L2? Are they your own modules or third party libraries?

Comment: My own libs, but on different projects. I will use L1 in a lot of other kotlin projects.,

Comment: It's probably how you're publishing L1. @GiorgosNeokleous is correct that you shouldn't need to put dependencies outside of common, but it's not really Kotlin 1.4. That's been true for some time. However, if your gradle metadata isn't published correctly, you won't resolve the dependencies properly. In summary, post the rest of your build config, along with how you're publishing.

Comment: how do I publish metadata? I don't find it in the kotlin doc

Comment: It's part of maven/gradle publish. If configured correctly, you don't need to do it as a distinct thing.

Comment: have you a sample somewhere? I publish everything, it don't work.

Comment: Hi, @seb! Please update the question - the L1 Gradle has no mention of publishing. How you're doing it? I assume you follow the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-publish-lib.html), is this correct?